# Prevent multi-choice jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/z897dhjd/) i have my web-site
Sorry, that it's on Russian, but it doen't metter.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

var but = $('<button class="confirm_button">Подтвердить</button>');

$('figure img').on("click", function() 
{
     $(this).addClass("playerchoose");
     $('.players').append(but);

});


});
```

As you see, I want to choose one of the figure element, and the do some evente, with button, that had added.

What jQuery methods i write, in order to prevent multi choise of figure elements? 
And another question is about removing all events, that appears while cliking on figure, while cliking it one more time

Comment: Try [`jquery.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/). And if you need to detach an event handler, you can use `off()`. But you probably would not need it in your case if you use `one()`.